# Highcharts: Is it possible to show Sunburst legend similar to Pie chart legend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Currently, on enabling the legend of sunburst chart in Highcharts, single series label is seen in legend. Refer following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/7r8eb5ms/6/

Highcharts pie chart legend shows the all the category labels in the legend. Refer following Pie chart legend: http://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/wgaak302/

```
series: [{
name: 'Sales',
colorByPoint: true,
showInLegend: true,
data: [{
  name: 'Consumer',
  y: 2455
}, {
  name: 'Corporate',
  y: 6802
},{
  name: 'Home office',
  y: 9031
}, {
  name: 'Small Business',
  y: 5551
}]
}]
```

Is it possible to show all the data points of the sunburst series or atleast the categories - Consumer, Corporate, Home Office, Small Business in legend?

Comment: It is my understanding the point of sunburst (with drill) is to show all segment labels in the chart - not in the legend.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the answer is **no**.

Please refer to this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/u3p1usz9/

I tried to implement this functionality by setting `legendType = 'point'` (not docummented in the API, but it works) and overwriting `H.Legend.prototype.getAllItems`, but it seems that hiding points is not supported for sunburst. There's no method that will do it - check out the `console.log` output. Switching visibility of the point by using `visible` property doesn't work either. Legend behaves properly, but there's no effect on the plot area.

**Workaround**

This simple example shows how to mimic desired legend behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/kn10kb7L/

First I added additional two series that have no data:

```
{
  type: 'line',
  name: 'p1',
  color: 'blue'
}, {
  type: 'line',
  name: 'p2',
  color: 'blue'
}
```

The color of the legend item markers needs to be handled manually by setting the color of the 'fake' series.
I created `visible` flag for every leaf for controlling its visibility.
Then I used their `legendItemClick` callback function to filter the full data set and perform `setData` on the first series using the filtered data.

```
    legendItemClick: function(e) {
      series = this;
      data.forEach(function(leaf) {
        if (leaf.id === series.name || leaf.parent === series.name) {
          leaf.visible = !leaf.visible;
        }
      });
      this.chart.series[0].setData(data.filter((leaf) => leaf.visible));
    }
```

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.sunburst.point.events.legendItemClick

---

If you think that hiding points should be implemented in sunburst series you can share this idea here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

---

**Update**

If you want an animation to happen use `addPoint` and `removePoint` instead of `setData`.

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#removePoint

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.It helped. I tried the solution of adding a dummy series and defining legendItemClick event. JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/kn10kb7L/1/
I am trying to achieve the same in actual sunburst chart that shows top level with a transparent innermost circle. Here the condition to hide the point is not satisfied. JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/7r8eb5ms/19/